# How to pass argumens when freezing a flask app?

Tags: python, flask

I want to deploy my flask app to netlify. I've understood that to do that I first have to freeze it. Below is how I've run it until now:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import requests
import json
from flask_frozen import Freezer

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/api')
def api():
    data = dict(request.args)
    print(data)
    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={data['question']}"
    x = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data))
    return 'Hello world'

app.run()
```

This runs fine. If I want to freeze it, I add:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import requests
import json
from flask_frozen import Freezer

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
freezer = Freezer(app)


@app.route('/api')
def api():
    data = dict(request.args)
    print(data)
    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={data['question']}"
    x = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data))
    return 'Hello world'

freezer.register_generator(api)
freezer.freeze()
```

I get an error:

> url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={data['question']}"
>
> KeyError: 'question'
>
> ...
>
> ValueError: Unexpected status '500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR' on URL /api

I've also tried

```
@app.route('/api/<question>')
def api(question):
    data = dict(request.args)
```

Which works fine when running the app. But when I freeze it, I get:

> TypeError: api() missing 1 required positional argument: 'question'

How do I freeze my app so that I deploy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flask-Frozen` is an extension which allows you to convert a Flask app into a set of static HTML files for deployment on a bog-standard webserver, which doesn't support Python.

This would work perfectly if your site has a predefined set of endpoints/pages (For example the frontend to a blog application) where all dynamic routes can be generated from a known set of database entires.

However this won't work for your code which calls `requests.post` on a Google URL.  To make this work you'd need to know every possible set of terms which a user might enter, and during the 'freezing' process it would make countless requests to that URL in order to generate the static pages which you will host.

---

Don't confuse this library with the separate `pip freeze` command, which is the method to freeze your Python requirements within an environment, typically to a `requirements.txt` file.

You may wish to take a look at the [Flask deployment docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/) to find a method which will work to deploy your app.